# Get page title without prefix or suffix

Tags: magento-1.7, seo, page-title

I want text in `<h1>` tag to match page title, but without store prefix.

I'm getting page title like so:

```
<h1>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle(); ?></h1>
```

How can I get page title without store prefix, or how can I retrieve store prefix option?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to do it.

To cut prefix:

```
<?php 
$prefix = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_prefix');
$title = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();
$processedTitle = trim(substr($title, strlen($prefix)));
?>
<h1><?php echo $processedTitle;?></h1>
```

To cut suffix:

```
<?php 
$suffix = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_suffix');
$title = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();
$processedTitle = substr($title, 0, strlen($suffix) * -1);
?>
<h1><?php echo $processedTitle;?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access the _data-Array directly:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getData('title');
```

Comment: Returns the same result for me, with store title.

Comment: yes, obviously. because the value of `_data` is changed. there is no way to get the original value back.